# How to unwrap a Single<Flowable<Sample>> to Flowable<Sample>?

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, rx-java, rx-java2

I have defined the following rxjava (Kotlin) code to create a non-blocking, backpressure sensitive generator.  The generator is fed a non-blocking stream of a JSON from Azure Blob Storage through a Jackson JSON Api JsonParser, which provides very specialize and fast parsing.  My downloadBlob() method returns a `Single<ByteBuffer>` to which I attach the generator.  I cannot figure out why the generator variable is being reported as a `Single<Flowable<Sample>>` rather than a `Flowable<Sample>`.  I'd appreciate your suggestions for extracting the `Flowable<Sample>`, which is what I need.  I have hit the wall on this issue... :(

Thank you for your help and time.

```
    /**
     * Method generator parses sample data from a json stream.
     * @param sampleJsonUrl String is the URL to the Azure Blob Storage sample data.
     * @return Flowable<Sample>> is a cold, synchronous, stateful and backpressure-aware
     * generator of features.
     */
fun generator(sampleJsonUrl: String) =
            blobStorage.downloadBlob(sampleJsonUrl)
                    .map { bbuf: ByteBuffer -> JsonFactory().createParser(bbuf.array()) }
                    .map { jParser ->
                        Flowable.generate<Sample, JsonParser>(
                                java.util.concurrent.Callable { jParser.gobbleJsonToSamples() },

                                io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer<JsonParser, Emitter<Sample>> { 
                                    parser: JsonParser, emitter: Emitter<Sample> ->
                                        pullOrComplete(parser, emitter)
                                },

                                Consumer<JsonParser> { jParser.close() }
                        )
                    }.flatMapPublisher { it }



    /**
     * Method downloadBlob will retrieve a blob from storage and return a 
     * reactive stream of bytes.
     * @param url String is the url to the blob.
     * @return Single<ByteBuffer> is the blob's content.
     */
    override fun downloadBlob(url: String): Single<ByteBuffer> =

            BlockBlobURL(URL(url), pipeline)
                    .download(null, null, false, null)
                    .flatMap {
                        FlowableUtil
                        .collectBytesInBuffer(
                            it.body(ReliableDownloadOptions().withMaxRetryRequests(3))
                        )
                    }
```

Comment: Use [`flatMapPublisher`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flatMapPublisher-io.reactivex.functions.Function-)

Comment: Thank you!  I will give it a go and report back. :)

Comment: Hi!  Your suggestion worked perfectly!  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I've modified the original code in this posting to the version that I am using.  It includes the recommendation from akarnokd at the end of the generator() and I've included my method that reactively downloads a blob's content from Azure Blob Storage and streams it into the generator for parsing via Jackson Json Api.  This code is using Azure Blob's Java SDK v11.